# Ошибка double free or corruption (fasttop)

Tags: c, указатели, динамические-массивы

В программе есть следующие функции:

```
void main(){
    char** text = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char*));
    int sentence = 0;
    printf(" Введите текст. Использоваться должны только латинские буквы и цифры. Слова отделяются пробелами или запятыми, предложения — точками.\n\n");
    text = text_input(text, &sentence);
    text = text_redaction(text, &sentence);
    menu(&text, &sentence);
}
```

Ввод:

```
char** text_input(char **text, int *sentence){
    int slen = 50;
    char ch;
    int symb = 0;

    while (ch != '\n'){
        text[*sentence] = (char*)malloc(slen * sizeof(char));
        while (ch != '.' && ch != '\n'){
            ch = getchar();
            if (ch == '\n'){
            break;
            }
            if (symb >= slen - 1){
                slen += 50;
                text[*sentence] = (char*)realloc(text[*sentence], slen * sizeof(char));
            }
            text[*sentence][symb++] = ch;
        }
        if (ch == '\n'){
        break;
        }
        ch = '\0';
        text[*sentence][symb] = ch;
        *sentence += 1;
        text = (char**)realloc(text, (*sentence + 1) * sizeof(char*));
        symb = 0;
        slen = 50;
    }
    return text;
}
```

Удаление предложений с нечётным кол-вом слов:

```
void odd_delete(char ***text, int *sentence){
    int count = 0;
    char *buf;
    for (int i = 0; i < *sentence; i++){
        buf = (char*)malloc((strlen((*text)[i])) * sizeof(char));
        memcpy(buf, (*text)[i], (strlen((*text)[i])+1) * sizeof(char));
        char *str = strtok(buf, " ,.\0");
        while(str != NULL){
            ++count;
            str = strtok(NULL, " ,.\0");
        }
        if (count % 2 != 0){
            free((*text)[i]);
            for (int j = i; j < *sentence; j++){
                (*text)[j] = (*text)[j+1];
            }
            free((*text)[*sentence - 1]);
            i -= 1;
            *sentence -= 1;
        }
        free(buf);
        count = 0;
    }
}
```

При вводе большинства предложений все работает, но иногда, например при вводе "qwe. Qwe. serht. qWe. rstjsr. qwE. weognho. QWE. erkjb kjwebgjk. oierfoi qowirngon rnefio eoirngo. wreoigno ewrigj weorigjn. woqiehfoih weifhoi wieofhoih weiofhoih wefihih wefoihoih. woefho weiofhoih weoifhioh woiefh woeifh." вылетает ошибка double free or corruption (fasttop). Можно ли это как-то исправить?

Comment: Ну так бери и дебажь...

Comment: Почему у `odd_delete` вдруг `char ***text`??? Откуда вдруг взялась третья `*`? Зачем она там?

Comment: @AnT Там огромный код, из которого я выбрал только три функции. А в самой программе функции передается указатель на указатель на двумерный динамический массив.

Comment: Это прекрасно. Но у вас в `text_input` параметр имеет тип `char **`. Чем `odd_delete` в этом плане отличается от `text_input`? Почему у `text_input` - `char **`, а в `odd_delete` вдруг `char ***`?

Comment: Вводится текст через присваивание, а далее в программе вызывается ряд функций, которые должны менять исходный текст определённым образом. В эти функции передаётся три звездочки (чтобы массив предложений не копировался и пользователь работал с исходным текстом)

Answer (score 2):

В `odd_delete` вот здесь написана какая-то ерунда

```
free((*text)[i]);
for (int j = i; j < *sentence; j++){ 
  (*text)[j] = (*text)[j+1];         // <- Выход за пределы массива 
}
free((*text)[*sentence - 1]);        // <- А это что такое вообще?
```

Во-первых, если у вас в массиве всего `*sentence` элементов, то этот цикл зачем то копирует влево лишний элемент `(*text)[*sentence]`, который находится за пределами массива. Цикл должен быть на 1 итерацию короче. Я бы переписал его вот так

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < *sentence; ++j++)
  (*text)[j - 1] = (*text)[j];
```

(или, лучше, воспользовался `memmove`).

Во-вторых, никакого `free` после цикла для последнего элемента делаться не должно. С чего бы это вдруг? Этот указатель был только что скопирован влево. Он вам еще нужен. Зачем вы на него напускаете `free`? Можете занулить эту "свободную" ячейку

```
(*text)[*sentence1 - 1] = NULL;
```

но и это не обязательно.

Другими словами, из кода надо просто выкинуть ваше

```
free((*text)[*sentence - 1]);
```

Это совершенно ненужная и некорректная операция. Именно из-за нее вы и получаете double free.

---

Отдельно не ясно, с чего это вдруг параметр `odd_delete` вдруг `char ***text`??? Откуда вдруг взялась третья `*`? Зачем она там?

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. По поводу трех звездочек: Там огромный код, из которого я выбрал только три функции. А в самой программе функции передается указатель на указатель на двумерный динамический массив.